# haskell, how to unwrap IO monad

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I can do:  `runIdentity`, `runErrorT` and more to unwrap inner monad.
However, What should I do in case of `IO (Either String Int)`  ? How to unwrap it ?

Comment: You don't 'unwrap' this type - you can 'unwrap' things like `Identity` and `ErrorT` because they are simply newtypes for other types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not unwrap `IO a` actions. Instead, you include them in the `main` action (which has an `IO` type, hence can use such actions) and the compiler ensures that `main` is executed.

You may also teach functions that do not understand `IO` how to handle `IO`; for example, we have:

```
fmap  :: (a ->    b) -> IO a -> IO b
(=<<) :: (a -> IO b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

Thus if you have a function which consumes an `Either String Int`, you may use one of the above functions to teach it how to consume an `IO (Either String Int)` instead.

For further reading, you may enjoy [The IO Monad for People Who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html). (I also like the monad tutorials [You Could Have Invented Monads! (And Maybe You Already Have.)](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) and [All About Monads](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads), though they are less directly relevant to this question.)

Comment: `fmap (+1) (IO 1)` give error: no constructor for `IO`

Comment: @HaskellFun You may teach pure values how to be `IO`-like with `return :: a -> IO a`.

Comment: It doesn't help me

Comment: @HaskellFun You'll have to say a bit more than that if you want help. Why didn't it help you? What did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: I would like to be able following thing:   `fmap (+1) (IO 21) = (IO 22)`

Comment: @HaskellFun As suggested in my previous comment: use `return`, as in `fmap (+1) (return 21)`.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to use `>>=` instead of do to wrap value from `IO` ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Yes, `do`-notation is desugared to calls to `(>>=)` and `return`. See [the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) for details, and recall the definition `m1 >> m2 = m1 >>= \_ -> m2`.

Comment: How to use `fmap` ?  I know that I unwrap on Right element closed in IO monad ? I mean: `fmap (+11) (IO (Right 12)) = IO (Right 23)`

Comment: @HaskellFun I encourage you to open a fresh top-level thread if you have further questions. Also note that `IO` is a type constructor, but there is *no* term constructor named `IO` -- so `IO (Right 12)` is not a good mental model to hold. Do follow through with the proposed further reading; I think it will clear up many of your misconceptions.