# Parsing IO [Int] to use the Int

Tags: list, parsing, haskell, io, integer

I am developing in Haskell and I had to use `System.Random`.

Now I have a `IO [Int]` and I would like to parse it to get the `Int` out of it and then use it to perform an action on a list.

I did:

```
function :: IO [Int] -> [a] -> a
function (x:xs) list = (list !! x)
```

But I get an error on `(x:xs)`:

```
 Couldn't match expected type 'IO [Int]' with actual type '[a0]'.
```

How do I parse the `IO [Int]` to use the `Int` inside?

Comment: You can not unwrap a value out of an `IO`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/36729022/67579

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so there is no way i can use these value ? But then I don't understand how can you use random in Haskell outside of the main to print. I can't do calcul with random since he only return a  IO Int ?

Comment: @Hrothgor You cannot unwrap an `IO` thing to pass on to a pure consumer. But you can wrap a pure consumer to accept `IO` things (and return `IO` things), with `fmap` or `(>>=)` depending on whether the function returns an `IO` thing or not.