# Random char number in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random

I want to generate random number in Haskell and to use this number for concatenation with my text. I found this function but it doesn't give me char type. How can I change this function?

```
rollDice :: IO Int 
rollDice = getStdRandom (randomR (1,3))
```

Comment: [Try Hoogle.](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20Char)

Comment: Why does the title says In C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`randomR :: (Random a, RandomGen g) => (a, a) -> g -> (a, g)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.2.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomR) can generate random items for any type that is an instance of the [**`Random`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.2.1/docs/System-Random.html#t:Random), hence for a `Char`, you can work with:

```
rollDice :: IO Char
rollDice = getStdRandom (randomR ('a', 'z'))
```

or for any value of `Char`:

```
rollDice :: IO Char
rollDice = getStdRandom random
```

Comment: Can I get type [Char] instead of usual Char?

Comment: @HandcraftingCountry: with `getStdRandom randoms`

Comment: ```
rollDice :: IO [Char] 
rollDice = getStdRandom (randoms ("1","3"))
```
Like this?

Comment: @HandcraftingCountry: no `getStdRandom (randomRs ('1','3'))`, but here it probably makes more sense to generate an `IO [Int]`, so `getStdRandom (randomRs (1,3))`

Comment: What if I want to use it us type [Char] in another function, but it's type (IO [Char]).  How can I delete this IO from type? (sorry for stupid questions)

Comment: @HandcraftingCountry: you don't: that's the entire point of `IO` to protect against impurity https://stackoverflow.com/q/36729022/67579